# how to remove secure boot isn't configured correctly watermark in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1

Recently, I've updated my Dell Laptop from windows `version 8 to 8.1`. After finishing the upgrading process it showing water mark in the left bottom of the screen states that

> secure boot isn't configured correctly watermark Built 9600.

How to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the update [KB2902864](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2902864/en-us) (**Update removes the "Windows 8.1 SecureBoot isn't configured correctly" watermark in Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2**)

Download it from the [Microsoft Download center](http://search.microsoft.com/en-us/DownloadResults.aspx?q=KB2902864).

Comment: Didn't work for me. Tried to install again, but it says already installed.

Comment: for me it worked. Is you windows activated?

Comment: Well ... after 3 reboots and a couple of shutdowns it just went away. So I guess it worked, but just not as quickly as I expected.